# Can't use variable to create custom swift color

Tags: swift, variables, colors

I'm trying to use the variables red, green, and blue to create a color that is random, but I get an error that says it can't convert the variable type into a CGFloat.

```
import UIKit
var red = arc4random_uniform(8) + 1;
var green = arc4random_uniform(8) + 1;
var blue = arc4random_uniform(8) + 1;

let containerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 300.0, height: 600.0))

let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 105.0, y: 215.0, width: 100.0, height: 100.0))
circle.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0
let startingColor = UIColor(red: (253.0/255.0), green: (159.0/255.0), blue: (47.0/255.0), alpha: 1.0)
circle.backgroundColor = startingColor

containerView.addSubview(circle);
```

Comment: that doesn't work because of the value of the variable but thanks

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do, considering you are not using the `red`, `green` and `blue` variables anywhere in your code and you forgot the small but very important detail of which is the line that throws that error, for which the solution is my previous comment.

Comment: I am trying to put red in place of (253.0/255.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
let startingColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(red), green: CGFloat(green), blue: CGFloat(blue), alpha: 1.0)
```